# newbie compilation error net/http Response

Tags: http, go, httpresponse

Why do I get a compilation error for this code?  Response type is defined in "net/http"

```
package main
import "net/http"
func main() {
}
func GetWithProxy(urlString string, proxyString string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    return nil, nil
}
```

error:

```
.\t.go:3: imported and not used: "net/http"
.\t.go:7: undefined: Response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining that you didn't use `net/http`, which you didn't.

```
package main

import "net/http"

func GetWithProxy(urlString string, proxyString string) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
        return nil, nil
}

func main() {
}
```

This will compile because now you are using `net/http`.  The compiler didn't know you were talking about `net/http's` `Response` type.

If you want 'absorb' `net/http's` namespace you can do:

```
package main
import . "net/http"

func GetWithProxy(urlString string, proxyString string) (resp *Response, err error) {
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
}
```

Observe:
https://play.golang.org/p/WH1NSzFhSV

Comment: thank you!  First option is better in terms of keeping the executable size small or are the both the same?

Comment: Binary size is the same across both solutions, but the first is better for readability in my opinion.

Comment: Please do not recommend dot-imports.

Comment: Dot imports should only be used in *very* specific circumstances. If you don't know what those circumstances are, don't use them.